# SQL Server Storage of Data: 4 gb Raw, how much in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 database and I have 4 GB of text files that I need to import into it. The question is, if these 4 GB of text files are 1.2 GB when they are zipped, how big would the database be if they are imported? Does SQL Server shrink data by default, or how would I set this (think create a database as a detached item, to be attached to another DB later).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server will not shrink data by default. In fact, there will be a small overhead per column and row, so it would require more space.

If you really must store those files in the DB (it is recommended that you don't), take a look at this [article](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2007/05/save-and-restore-filesimages-to-sql.html) I blogged a while back.  In SQL Server 2008, they have introduced the FILESTREAM type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary factors:

- Indexing will increase the space requirement.
- Normalization will decrease the space requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic compression - although you could put compressed data in columns it will be difficult to search.

Are these being imported into a set of normalized tables?  Are there spaces or other data which will be stripped (commas)?

If so, you can expect space savings from the normalization and the trimming of spaces.